# What is the "data-template" attribute on body tags I find in Twig templates?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I frequently see body tags in Twig templates that look like this:

```
<body class="..." data-template="base.twig">
```

I'd like to know what the purpose of the data-template attribute is. I'm not sure if this is relevant to Twig specifically, or the Timber plugin for Wordpress. Any links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably just some debug information to let you know which template(s) are rendered where inside the `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm, It's for debug help